# LibGdx: Utilizing a Gesture Listener

Tags: java, input, libgdx, gesture

I would like to use some of the more complex touch screen gestures that you can't access from

```
Gdx.input
```

I saw that to do this i must create a Gesture listener so i created the class GestureHandler and copied the code from the [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/InputGestureDetection). My gesture handler looks like this:

```
public class GestureHandler implements GestureListener {

@Override
public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean tap(float x, float y, int count, int button) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean longPress(float x, float y) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean zoom(float initialDistance, float distance) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean pinch(Vector2 initialPointer1, Vector2 initialPointer2, Vector2 pointer1, Vector2 pointer2) {
    return false;
    }   
 }
```

My question is now that i have set up the gesture listener how can i use it. How can i get the info from these methods? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/InputGestureDetection):

> A `GestureDetector` is an `InputProcessor` in disguise. To listen for
>   gestures, one has to implement the `GestureListener` interface and
>   pass it to the constructor of the `GestureDetector`. The detector is
>   then set as an `InputProcessor`, either on an `InputMultiplexer` or as
>   the main `InputProcessor`

I admit that is rather dense.  But a bit farther down on the wiki you'll see:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GestureDetector(new MyGestureListener()));
```

To rephrase the above in hopefully less dense English: *Your* `GestureHandler` instance is passed to a *Libgdx* `GestureDetector` instance.  That object will accumulate "raw" inputs and convert them into higher-level "gestures".  To get the raw inputs, it needs to be installed where the raw inputs will be delivered to it.  The most basic way to install it via `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor`, but you could also install it via an `InputMultiplexer` (but that's not worth getting into here).

Comment: So Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GestureDetector(new GestureHandler()); sets the input but then how can i access these gestures because all of the methods just return a boolean and i want the paramaters for example: public boolean longPress(float x, float y) i want the x and y variables

Comment: Put your code that wants those values inside the callback.  Your code may have to be structured a little differently to handle input "events" like this (vs. a "polling" architecture).

Comment: You mean inside the GestureHandler class? EX.longPress(float x, float y) {x = 0}

Comment: Yes and no.  Yes: put your code inside the `longPress` callback.  E.g., `boolean longPress(float x, float y) { Gdx.app.log("tag", "Got long press at " +x+ ", " +y); return true }`.  No: The `x = 0;` won't really do anything.  I think this might help: http://www.vogella.com/articles/DesignPatternObserver/article.html

Comment: This is a bit off topic but have you ever had any problems with the zoom gesture because it seems to be picking up my zoom gesture as a long touch and every touch is being picked up as a long touch even when its a short touch i tried altering the constructor but it still isnt working.