# How to use Libgdx gesture detector

Tags: libgdx, gesturedetector

I'm new at Libgdx and one aspect that blocks me to continue with my Libgdx learning is the fact that a I don't know how to use the GestureListener. It's seems there's a user with the same doubt if you see in this link [LibGdx: Utilizing a Gesture Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891366/libgdx-utilizing-a-gesture-listener), but it didn't help me much. So my question is: how do I use my own GestureListener class to process my player moviments? I wanna use the pan function to make it jump, but I don't know how to put my player object inside the method. If you see my gesture detector class:

```
public class GestureHandler implements GestureListener {
// Main Game class
private ClimbUp mainGame;

public GestureHandler(ClimbUp game) {
    this.mainGame = game;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean tap(float x, float y, int count, int button) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean longPress(float x, float y) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

...
```

Then I followed what they told the user what to do: in the main class I passed the fallowing instruction:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GestureDetector(new GestureHandler(this)));
```

Now in my splash screen, I don't know how to use. How to make my GestureHandler object works for all project? I'll be very grateful with an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have some you class which need GestureListener "services" - you want to be informed when some gesture event happens and you want to have information of gesture properties.

Then, as you did, make your class implement GestureListener interface.

After that your IDE (Eclipse or Android Studio or something else) will complain that you didn't implemented all GestureListener methods, but it can also do that for you. If you (in eclipse) hover the error in the code IDE will offer you to create missing methods.

I would say you are at about that step. But now your methods have to do something useful. Like, if you want to do something when player taps the screen add your code inside that method. Do something there. Inside GestureListener methods you have some info available, as method parameters  like x & y coordinates, button (left, middle, right) and something like that.

So, when you call that setInputProcessor with object created in you class that implemented G.L. interface libGDX will know to call your methods when some event occurs.

Every method IDE generated has that "todo" mark - that's where you have to put your code instead. The code that will handle that event, move your space ship, fire the bullet or what ever. You don't have to do something for every event, but only for those you are interested in. You can leave other empty, but your class must have them.

Here is some example:

```
// importing interface
import com.badlogic.gdx.input.GestureDetector.GestureListener;

// defining my class that implements that interface
public class TouchController implements GestureListener{

// constructor - just storing objects passed to it.
    public TouchController(Playground pg, Army army, Hud hud){
        super();
        this.pg = pg;
        this.army = army;
        this.hud = hud;
        initialZoom = pg.zoom;
    }

// Adding some action to touchDown method - I'm just calling my hud object's method and passing coords I get
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        hud.pressedAt(x, pg.camera.viewportHeight-y); // opposite Y axis
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

// Similar thing. I unproject coords I get.
    @Override
    public boolean tap(float x, float y, int count, int button) {
        if (!hud.buttonPressed){
            Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
            touchPos.set(x, y, 0);
            pg.camera.unproject(touchPos);
            army.add(touchPos.x, touchPos.y, SoldierSide.RED);
        }else hud.released();
        return false;
    }

// Again similar stuff, but this pan methods is getting also delta value (difference from last reading x and y values) which can be useful
    @Override
    public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
        if (hud.aimDrag) hud.aimDragged((int)deltaX, (int)deltaY);
        else if (hud.sliderDrag) hud.sliderDragged((int)deltaX, (int)deltaY);
        else if (!hud.buttonPressed) pg.panned((int)deltaX, (int)deltaY);
        return false;
    }

...
```

Comment: I didn't get it very well. So I have to create my Player class inside the method? Do you have a code as example to show me?

Comment: No, you just have to put your code that should be executed inside those empty methods IDE created for you. You have your "GestureHandler" class which implemented that "GestureListener" interface and because of that your class has some additional methods. Those methods will be called (executed) when some even occurs. So, you just have to put you code inside those methods, which will do something when event happens.

Comment: May you show me some code example (link, etc)? It'd be very useful not just for me but other users that have  the same doubt.

Comment: Added some example in answer above.

Comment: So in this case I should "register" my player class inside the GestureHandler class. If its that, you helped me.

Comment: Hmm...that GestureHandler class contains your code that will be called by libGDX when some even occurs. So, you created it, made it implement GestureListener interface (you have follow the rules libGDX made), created all needed methods from that interface and in some (or all) you placed your code that will handle those events. So, when you register your GestureHandler object libGDX will officially know that when even occurs your object's methods should be called and they will handle those even - react on them.

Comment: Yes, I put all the objects in the main class, so my GestureHandler can access all objects of that class because I used it in the constructor. Solved !!

Comment: Actually GestureHandler is you class. You could name it how ever you want (you noticed that I named it differently in my example!) and you could add new variables and new methods as you wish. Only obligation is to have all the methods defined by GestureListener since you are implementing it. Implementing means that you will provide needed methods. Even more, you can even implement 2 or more interfaces in you class (i.e. implement also that desktop controller class too). Point is that system knows what methods with what parameters it needs to call (interface), so you have to provide them.

Comment: Check out this to clear it even more: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm